# Gift wrap still showing when disabled in Admin

Tags: magento2, error, shopping-cart, giftmessage

I met an issue when using gift wrap of M2.
I added gift wrap in Shopping cart, then I disabled that gift wrap in Admin but it's still showing and applying amount into cart like the below image.

[image]

It's the default Magento

Answer (score 1):

After making any changes in store configurations you should clear your cache from admin (**System->Cache Management->Flush Cache** ) / CLI ( **php bin/magento cache:flush** )

However if you are in default mode ( to check run command **php bin/magento deploy:mode:show** ). Then give a try by deploying static content ( **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f** ) again and flush cache.

Comment: It seems not work :(

Comment: which changing configurations, make sure you have made settings in relevant store ( from top Store View drop down ) secondly did you enabled this from store configurations or layout ?